# Remove references in a shared object to another shared object

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

I want to remove references in a shared object to symbols of another shared object because the referenced object is GPL'd and I don't want to release my code under that license. (I don't think that the symbols provided by the referenced object are used by my code.) What are the steps to take to do this on Linux? I'm not steeped in this technology and it would help if you provided commands. Would another approach be better? Would it be better to somehow create a stub object replacing the referenced object?

Edit 1: I am using PyInstaller to build a self-contained archive containing the binaries for the code I've written along with all libraries that code requires and all libraries those libraries require. These libraries are shared objects that already exist on the build system. It would be too much work to forego PyInstaller and re-compile everything so that the GPL'd libraries are not linked in.

Comment: If the symbols in the GPL'd library are not referenced by you, why are you linking with it?

Comment: They are referenced by a library that I am linking with.

Comment: Then that library must also be GPLd, and so must your code.

Answer (score 3):

On Linux, the only libraries directly referenced by an executable or library are `libc.so`, `ld-linux.so`, `linux-gate.so`, plus anything you *explicitly request on the compiler command line*. As such, you can remove these references simply by removing them from the compiler command line.

Note that many times, `pkg-config` scripts will return all indirect dependencies as well as direct dependencies when queried for linker flags. You can either remove the unnecessary dependencies manually, or pass the `-Wl,--as-needed` flag to the linker to instruct it to remove unnecessary direct references to shared libraries automatically.

As for the pyinstaller bundling, keep in mind that indirectly linking GPL'd libraries via an intermediate library is already kind of a grey area; if you in addition merge them into a single file, this may not count as 'mere aggregation' and may not avoid the GPL restrictions. Also note that the GPL never mentions 'linking'; it's all about derivative works. I'm no lawyer and this is not legal advice, but the mere addition or removal of a NEEDED entry for a GPL'd library when no symbols are used seems unlikely to affect whether you are in violation of the GPL, when the GPL itself never mentions such a thing.

Comment: Thanks for your additional advice (+1). I've also heard, as you say, that linking dynamically to GPL libraries is a grey area and I'd like to avoid it. I may be able to use elfsh to remove these references so that there's less uncertainty.